# Media query not working on mobile, works fine on laptop

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I have seen this question answered many times on Stack Overflow. My media query seems to be working fine on my laptop using Chrome, but it doesn't work on my mobile device. Each answer on SO says to include this tag in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

I have it in my header (using Pug), and it's still not working on my mobile device. Anyone know what could be causing this?

On laptop:
[image]

On mobile:
[image]

Header

```
html
  head
    title My site
    meta(name="description" content="A cool thing made with Glitch")
    link#favicon(rel="icon" href="https://glitch.com/edit/favicon-app.ico" type="image/x-icon")
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/layout.css")

    block extralink
    block extrascript

    script(src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous")
```

.css

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
    }

    td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        content: attr(data-before);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is no a technical description of a problem. What's not working? In addition, the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Your CSS won't work in mobile because of the max-width constraint. You'd need to write CSS for mobile as well. or remove the max with and only write what you need for mobile. If that makes sense.

Comment: As you are using bootstrap, it should work. You must wrap your table like this `<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>`

Comment: @ronaldtgi Although I'm using Bootstrap for other elements of my design, I actually don't want to use Bootstrap for the table. I don't like how their responsive tables look, having to scroll horizontally on small screens. I like the look having the categories stacked to the side (like how it looks on the laptop view above), so that was what I was hoping to get on my phone as well. The CSS as written works. If I use my laptop and shrink the window, it's behaving as I want. It's just not being picked up on the mobile device for some reason.

Comment: @Scott , Although you're using table tags with pure CSS, Bootstrap original CSS may affect your table, also, to make a table to be responsive is a lot of works. If you don't like Boostrap responsive table, you can use bootstrap column grids or flex.